# How does UIProgressView get information on animation duration?

Tags: ios, objective-c, progress-bar, uiprogressview

I'm working on circular progress view and it's working quite cool. But I'd like to make it more flexible, so user would use it like a normal `UIProgressView` paired with `NSTimer`. I cannot figure how to make equivalent of: `setProgress:(float)progress animated:(BOOL)animated`? For now I'm testing with hardcoded values and durations so it's animating nicely, but surely it can be somehow achieved to inform on exact duration value?

Comment: for now 'm not interested in just writing method where I pass time interval and it's handling timer and setting current progress - unless it cannot be done otherwise

Answer (score 0):

got it with `CAMediaTimingFunction` which I put inside my method updating `CGPath`

`if (self.continuous) {
        CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
        //animation.duration = 0.5;
        animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:prevValue];
        animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:_value];
        animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
        [self.progressLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"strokeEndAnimation"];
    }`